# Validation for array objects using class-validator in node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, class-validator

i want to validate alcoholeId and alcoholeName if it is empty.here is my format:

```
   {
     "barId": "string",
     "barName": "string",
     "drinksItems": [
      {
      "alcoholId": "string",
      "alcoholName": "string",
      "mixerList": [
         {
           "mixerId": "string"
         }
       ],
      "modifierList": [
         {
           "modifierId": "string"
         }
       ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to have an entity and to use `@ValidateNested` and `@Type` to cast it correctly (only in case of you use `class-transformer`).

```js
class Alcohol {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    alcoholId: string;
    @IsNotEmpty()
    alcoholName: string;
}

class Bar {
    @IsNotEmpty() // <- requires the array to be present
    @ValidateNested()
    // @Type(() => Alcohol) // <- add only if you use class-transformer
    alcohols: Array<Alcohol>;
}
```